# Adding metatags to Header in ASPX page

Tags: asp.net, header, meta-tags, literals

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
    base.OnLoad(e);
    Literal lTags = new Literal();
    lTags.Text = "<meta name=\"MetaTagsDemo\" content=\"Meta demo tag\" />";
        this.Header.Controls.Add(lTags);
}
```

I have the the above code in my default.aspx.cs. When Default.aspx page is loaded I do see the control getting added within  section but on top of the page (very 1st line in the page), the html display is "".

What am I doing wrong here?

I have another page named Browse.aspx where I have the same feature but this page doesn't show the html output.

Answer (score 1):

Your control lTags is a `Literal`, but it should be a `HtmlMeta`.

If you want to use a `Literal`, you need to include the entire meta tag in the Text property -

```
lTags.Text = "<meta name=\"MetaTagsDemo\" content=\"Meta demo tag\" />".
```

Otherwise, use `HtmlMeta`:

```
HtmlMeta lTags = new HtmlMeta();
lTags.Name = "MetaTagsDemo";
lTags.Content = "Meta demo tags";
```

Comment: My lTags.text is as below but it still shows up.  lTags.text ="<META NAME="DESCRIPTION" CONTENT="Home web1">  <META NAME="ABSTRACT" CONTENT="Home web2">  <META NAME="KEYWORDS" CONTENT="Home web3">"

Comment: What is the html output on the page?

Comment: I have updated original post with correct details. Please let me know...thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the code from the Browse page and can you post the actual HTML output.